# What Lua pattern behaves like a regex negative lookahead?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

my problem is I need to write a Lua code to interpret a text file and match lines with a pattern like

> ```
> if line_str:match(myPattern) then do myAction(arg) end
> ```

Let's say I want a pattern to match lines containing "hello" in any context except one containing "hello world". I found that in regex, what I want is called negative lookahead, and you would write it like

> .*hello (?!world).*

but I'm struggling to find the Lua version of this.

Comment: It is not possible within one Lua pattern. You need a full-fledged regex support for this. Why not check if a string contains `hello` but does not contain ``hello world``?

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I want a pattern to match lines containing "hello" in any context except one containing "hello world".

As Wiktor has correctly pointed out, the simplest way to write this would be `line:find"hello" and not line:find"hello world"` (you can use both `find` and `match` here, but `find` is probably more performant; you can also turn off pattern matching for `find`).

---

> I found that in regex, what I want is called negative lookahead, and
> you would write it like `.*hello (?!world).*`

That's incorrect. If you checked against the existence of such a match, all it would tell you would be that there *exists* a "hello" which is *not* followed by a "world". The string `hello hello world` would match this, despite containing "hello world".

Negative lookahead is a questionable feature anyways as it isn't trivially provided by actually *regular* expressions and thus may not be implemented in linear time.

If you really need it, look into [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/); negative lookahead is implemented as `pattern1 - pattern2` there.

Finally, the RegEx may be translated to "just Lua" simply by searching for (1) the pattern without the negative part (2) the pattern with the negative part and checking whether there is a match in (1) that is not in (2) simply by counting:

```lua
local hello_count = 0; for _ in line:gmatch"hello" do hello_count = hello_count + 1 end
local helloworld_count = 0; for _ in line:gmatch"helloworld" do helloworld_count = helloworld_count + 1 end
if hello_count > helloworld_count then
    -- there is a "hello" not followed by a "world"
end
```

Comment: I may not have worded it correctly in the original post, but the regex behavior is what I'm looking for. Suppose you had a repository and you're looking for occurrences of variables named "soap", but you don't want it to trigger on "soapbox", then you still want to see lines that contain both "soap" and "soapbox".

Comment: @QwertYuiop then the code snippet (or LPeg) should be for you.